# How to recall a value from a different ObserveEvent in R?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I have different ObreveEvent in Server(app) in R, I wanna recall a value from a previous ObserveEvent and use it in a new ObserveEvent. I think I have to use the "reactive" function but I don't know ho to manage it! Can you help me with a very short example?

Comment: It would be useful if you could provide more details.  In principle `observeEvent` / `observe` use `eager evaluation`, & do not provide a value.  You could 'force' them to provide one either using reactive values or using the `<<-` assignment (it depends from the use case). In contrast `reactive` / `eventReactive` use lazy eval. & provide values.  Maybe you could show with some code what you are attempting to do, even if it doesn't work. This would make it simpler to help.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean, but sounds like a use case for [`reactiveValues`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/reactiveValues.html)